# Resizing a background image, as it's too big for the browser

Tags: html, css

So I'm designing a web page that is incomplete atm, it's only missing 2 buttons so its fairly simple. Instead of messing around with Divs and css styling I decided to make the background in photoshop. I created the image in a resolution of 1920x1080, when I apply the image as the background it doesn't fit the browser window so the bottom right corner is missing. Is there any code I can add to fix this issue or is my best option just recreating the image at a smaller resolution and if so, what resolution should I build for?

Here is a link to page in case I didn't explain clearly enough:
http://www.itss.brockport.edu/~rsiss1/cis442/BulletinBoard/BulletinBoard

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>BulletinBoard</title>
<style>
body {background: url(BulletinBoardBg.jpg);
    background-position: center no-repeat;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use `background-size: cover;` but to be honest, you're asking for trouble using a static image as your layout. Different monitors have different resolutions, so it will never look the same for everyone. Unless this is just a mock-up/wireframe, you're better off "messing around with Divs and css styling" especially for just 2 buttons.

Comment: Yeah I decided to just tough it out and use divs and css, the answers worked for the most part until you resize the browser window. As I want the buttons to sit in the corresponding boxes on that image.

Comment: Really just don't. You'll never get it right for every browser. You should learn to mess with divs and css (or buttons in this case). And while you are at, move to HTML5 please!

Comment: It's for a class so we basically have to do as instructed otherwise I would be using html5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the CSS property

```
background-size: cover;
```

There's also `background-size: contain` if you *must* have the entire image on screen and don't mind extra space around the edges.

[Here's a reference for `background-size` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Comment: This works for the most part, until I decide to resize the browser. I'm adding "invisible" buttons into the boxes at the bottom of the image so when I resize the browser it adds multiple copies of the background going vertically. So I'll prolly just decide to tough it out and mess with divs to get the same desired effect.

Will accept when time allows, thank you.